# I have a ruby project that needs a submodule from github

Tags: git, clone, git-submodules, git-checkout

I have a typical ruby project and I would like to include a submodule within that project. The submodule lives on github. How do I use the git submodule command to include the submodule in my projects vender/plugins directory?

Thanks.

Comment: -1: **"This question does not show any research effort"**. Did you try `git submodule --help`? This is the most basic possible usage of the submodule command, and you should be able to answer this yourself with even the smallest amount of effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `git submodule --help` we can see:

```
git submodule [--quiet] add [-b branch] [-f|--force]
              [--reference <repository>] [--] <repository> [<path>]
```

So, given a repository "my-plugin" at "git@github.com:my-user/my-plugin.git", you would use

```
git submodule add git@github.com/my-user/my-plugin.git vendor/plugins/my-plugin
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 git submodule add (url of repo) vender/plugins/(submodule name)
```

[Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/) is a good reference for common git commands